# Pandas merge to list by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Is there a way to merge two pandas dataframes so that same column names end up as list entries in the merged df?
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : [4,5,6], 'C' : [7,8,9]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : ['a','b','c'], 'C' : ['d','e','f']})

df_merged = df_1.merge(df_2, on='A') # This should be changed, I guess
```

results in:

```
   A  B_x  C_x B_y C_y
0  1    4    7   a   d
1  2    5    8   b   e
2  3    6    9   c   f
```

I was hoping for:

```
   A  B       C
0  1  [4, a]  [7, d]
1  2  [5, b]  [8, e]
2  3  [6, c]  [9, f]
```

So it is similar to the `groupby.apply(list)` function, but for merging dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC we can do `groupby` with `axis=1`

```
s=df_1.merge(df_2, on='A').set_index('A')
s=s.groupby(s.columns.str.split('_').str[0],axis=1).agg(lambda x : x.tolist()).reset_index()
s
   A       B       C
0  1  [4, a]  [7, d]
1  2  [5, b]  [8, e]
2  3  [6, c]  [9, f]
```